# Receiving a TcpClient message from telnet asynchonously/in bulk

Tags: .net, tcpclient

First question on SO, apologies in advance for messups.

I'm tinkering with TcpClient attempting to make a prototype MUD server.  Using various solutions on SO I've started several test servers and connected to them with MUD clients and telnet.  I've noticed that with any solution I try, when I enter a command via Telnet, typed characters are streamed synchronously.  I'm wondering:

- Is this (non-)ideal?
- Is there a way to negotiate with Telnet clients to send messages in bulk?
- How do I handle it if its normal?  Do I inspect bytes as they come in and look for terminators such as \r\n?

I don't have specific server code as such; the question is more general about how communications with Telnet (particularly in a command/messaging situation) are handled.

Comment: TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not messages. So yes, it's up to you to work out how to identify and separate "messages" (such as here, detecting line ending characters)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not a code question @mohammadmobasher, just curious about the protocol.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, its about as expected.  I'll process the stream accordingly.